# How do I destroy the wooden blocks of underground rooms?

Tags: terraria

I wanted to create a "hellevator" and tunnel straight down, but I encountered an obstacle in the form of a wooden room underground. My Nightmare pickaxe seems to be unable to destroy the wooden block perimeter of this room

[image]

How can I destroy these wooden blocks to continue digging down?

Comment: I'm going to edit this for clarity, as in terraria, walls generally mean the background tiles, which are broken with a hammer.

Comment: @Mad Scientist You might want to reconsider which answer you have accepted due to updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Terraria 1.2, wood blocks are now mined with a pickaxe as well. Axes and chainsaws are now reserved for trees, giant mushrooms and cacti. They are no longer used for solid blocks.